# Changing signs of partial derivative's elements

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks

If

$C = \frac{1}{2}(y - a)^2$

where $y$ is a given value, $a = \sigma(z)$, and $z = wx + b$.

Then the partial derivative of $C$ with respect to w should be:
            $\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} = (y-a)\sigma'(z)$

However, Michael Nielsen wrote this in his book Neural Networks and Deep Learning:
            $\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} = (y-a)\sigma'(z)x$

Why could he change the signs of $a$ and $y$ in the right side of the partial derivative expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember:
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} =
\frac{\partial C}{\partial a} 
\frac{\partial a}{\partial z} 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial w} 
$$

Comment: @Jason No; that would mean $\partial C/\partial a=\partial C/\partial y$, but obviously the chain rule implies $\partial C/\partial a=-\partial C/\partial y$ . Equivalently, note $C=(a-y)^2/2$.

Comment: Oh, NOW I see. Sorry for my rusty calculus memory, hence. such a trivial question. Thanks, Matti!

Answer (score 1):

The one written by Michael Nielsen is correct. There is a minus sign in front of $a$ in $C = \frac{1}{2}(y-a)^{2}$, so from the chain rule we must remember to multiply by $-1$ when computing the derivative, i.e. $\frac{\partial C}{\partial w} = (y-a) \times (-1)\times \frac{\partial a}{\partial w}$.

Comment: Perfect explanation!